# Strange mysql "access denied" error

Tags: mysql, database-migration, mariadb

I have a strange (in my opinion) problem.

I am migrating a web application that uses a database. 
Accessing from the administrators login page there are no problems,
 but if I try to access the db from the users login page, 
the server responds with an error like

`"Access denied for user ' myuser ' @ ' localhost ' ( using password : YES)"`.

For the connection i use a separate .php file (included in both pages named above) with the root parameters and I really can't understand why the server tries to access with a mysql user that is only on my pc.
Thank you.
P.S. Locally everything works fine.

Comment: You almost certainly have two different .php files you're including by mistake

Comment: I searched in all the files but there are not files with that "myuser" parameters. Sure that it can be the only cause? It's really driving me crazy

Comment: Unless you've accidentally hard-coded the user is one of the files? You've definitely got that user in the code somewhere, there's no way for it to magically migrate

Comment: Well, I deleted everything and uploaded it again, now everything is fine. I think I accidentally uploaded a file that gave me that error. Thank you so much for your patience and help!

Comment: Look for a file in the home dir named .my.cnf, in the /etc/my.cnf under the section [client] or the php.ini to find the username